# Color conversion from RGB to YUV (YCoCg)

Tags: c++, halide

I'm trying to implement a color conversion `Func` that outputs to 3 separate buffers. The `rgb_to_ycocg` function has a 4x8bit channel interleaved buffer (BGRA) and 3 output buffers (Y, Co and Cg) which are each 16bit values. Currently, I'm using this piece of code:

```
void rgb_to_ycocg(const uint8_t *pSrc, int32_t srcStep, int16_t *pDst[3], int32_t dstStep[3], int width, int height)
{
    Buffer<uint8_t> inRgb((uint8_t *)pSrc, 4, width, height);
    Buffer<int16_t> outY(pDst[0], width, height);
    Buffer<int16_t> outCo(pDst[1], width, height);
    Buffer<int16_t> outCg(pDst[2], width, height);

    Var x, y, c;
    Func calcY, calcCo, calcCg, inRgb16;

    inRgb16(c, x, y) = cast<int16_t>(inRgb(c, x, y));

    calcY(x, y) = (inRgb16(0, x, y) + ((inRgb16(2, x, y) - inRgb16(0, x, y)) >> 1)) + ((inRgb16(1, x, y) - (inRgb16(0, x, y) + ((inRgb16(2, x, y) - inRgb16(0, x, y)) >> 1))) >> 1);
    calcCo(x, y) = inRgb16(2, x, y) - inRgb16(0, x, y);
    calcCg(x, y) =  inRgb16(1, x, y) - (inRgb16(0, x, y) + ((inRgb16(2, x, y) - inRgb16(0, x, y)) >> 1));

    Pipeline p =Pipeline({calcY, calcCo, calcCg});
    p.vectorize(x, 16).parallel(y);
    p.realize({ outY, outCo, outCg });
}
```

The issue is, I'm getting poor performance compared to the reference implementation (basic for loops in c). I understand I need to try better scheduling, but I think I'm doing something wrong in terms of input/output buffers. I've seen the tutorials and tried to come up with a way to output to multiple buffers. Using a `Pipeline` was the only way I could find. Would I be better off making 3 `Func`s and calling them separately? Is this a correct use of the `Pipeline` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big possible problem here is that you're making and compiling a code every time you want to convert a single image. That would be really really slow. Use ImageParams instead of Buffers, define the Pipeline once, and then realize it multiple times.

A second-order effect is that I think you actually want a Tuple rather than a Pipeline. A Tuple Func computes all its values in the same inner loop, which will reuse the loads from inRgb, etc. Ignoring the recompilation problem for the moment, try:

```
void rgb_to_ycocg(const uint8_t *pSrc, int32_t srcStep, int16_t *pDst[3], int32_t dstStep[3], int width, int height)
{
    Buffer<uint8_t> inRgb((uint8_t *)pSrc, 4, width, height);
    Buffer<int16_t> outY(pDst[0], width, height);
    Buffer<int16_t> outCo(pDst[1], width, height);
    Buffer<int16_t> outCg(pDst[2], width, height);

    Var x, y, c;
    Func calcY, calcCo, calcCg, inRgb16;

    inRgb16(c, x, y) = cast<int16_t>(inRgb(c, x, y));

    out(x, y) = {
        inRgb16(0, x, y) + ((inRgb16(2, x, y) - inRgb16(0, x, y)) >> 1)) + ((inRgb16(1, x, y) - (inRgb16(0, x, y) + ((inRgb16(2, x, y) - inRgb16(0, x, y)) >> 1))) >> 1),
        inRgb16(2, x, y) - inRgb16(0, x, y),
        inRgb16(1, x, y) - (inRgb16(0, x, y) + ((inRgb16(2, x, y) - inRgb16(0, x, y)) >> 1))
    };

    out.vectorize(x, 16).parallel(y);
    out.realize({ outY, outCo, outCg });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'm aware of the recompilation problem, but I'm happy to see it can be done with tuples. I'll try this tomorrow. thanks again!